# Reading/Deserializing json File in WP8.1 C#

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently trying to read Json file (named initial_data.json) which reside in the folder DataModels in my Project folder. The problem I'm having is it won't read the file. I have tried the following code to read the file to json string (which I will use it to deserialize later, so I've tried to display it into resultTextBlock) and nothing has came out.
Here's my Json file format

```
{
"brands": [
    {
        "id": "AUD",
        "name": "AUDI",
        "sort": "99",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "BEN",
        "name": "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "sort": "6",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "BMW",
        "name": "BMW",
        "sort": "7",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "CHE",
        "name": "CHEVROLET",
        "sort": "8",
        "active": true
    }
   ],
 "models": [
    {
        "id": "100",
        "name": "CIVIC",
        "brandID": "HON",
        "size": null,
        "year": "-",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "101",
        "name": "CRV",
        "brandID": "HON",
        "size": null,
        "year": "-",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "102",
        "name": "CRVEXI",
        "brandID": "HON",
        "size": null,
        "year": "-",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "id": "103",
        "name": "GDYSSEY",
        "brandID": "HON",
        "size": null,
        "year": "-",
        "active": true
    }
 ]
```

}

Here's my json Class

```
public class Brand
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sort")]
    public string sort { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("active")]
    public bool active { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("path")]
    public string path { get; set; }
}


public class Model
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("brandID")]
    public string brandID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public object size { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("year")]
    public string year { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("active")]
    public bool active { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how I write my reading function

```
private async Task readJsonAsync()
    {
        // Notice that the write **IS** identical ... except for the serializer.

        string content = String.Empty;

        var myStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(JSONFILENAME);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream))
        {
            content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        resultTextBlock.Text = content;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

think there might be some issue with the path you specified for the file name.

Please put your file in assets folder and follow the below code

```
        var fileStream = File.OpenRead("Assets/" + "sampleJson.txt");//You can specify your file name here.
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
          var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back! I was wandering around but still couldn't find that OpenRead Method. In fact I couldn't find "File" as well. When I use your given code, it says The name "File" does not exists in the current method. (I've already typed using System.IO; up top)